# Batch file: re-run command until output contains keyword

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch script where I want to run a particular command (which outputs a status) until its output contains a particular keyword. I'm not sure either of how to loop like this in a batch script nor of how to save and parse the output of a command.

I've tried an approach as described in Raymond Chen's ["Reading the output of a command into a batch file variable"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120731-00/?p=7003) (which uses a for loop to parse command output), without success (it's quite possible that I'm simply mangling or misunderstanding the commands). Any suggestions for how to repeat a command, parse its output, and repeat until the output is acceptable?

Comment: Edit your question and post what did you tried as code until now !

Comment: @Hackoo I could try to do it again and then post the code that wasn't working, but I'm not sure how useful that would be. I _tried_ to do something like what was in the article that I linked to, but I was getting syntax errors and my goal wasn't necessarily to get the correct syntax for the approach shown in the article, but to get the script to work as described here. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

no need to put the output into a variable for this. Just:

```
:loop
timeout /t 1 >nul
command | find "this is what I want"    
if errorlevel 1 goto :loop
echo successful.
```